# Old unchanged Test Method Fails during deployment of unrelated code

Tags: deployment, error, list, record-type, failing-tests

There are similar questions but they hold no answers and are not specific.

Error Message / Test Failed during deployment of unrelated code:

```
Test_Method_Test    ThisTest    System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0
Stack Trace: Class.Test_Method_Test.thisTest: line 101, column 1
```

Code that Passes when run during independent test, but fails during deployment.
 (last line below is line 101):

```
@isTest (SeeAllData=true)
private class Test_Method_Test {
    static testMethod void thisTest() {
        list<recordType> RTs = [SELECT id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Asset' AND Name = 'Machine Asset'];
        Asset a = new Asset();
        a.recordtypeId = RTs[0].id;
```

Asset exists and query returns 1 result.

Why would this fail during unrelated deployment?
Seems like Salesforce Bug???
I will escalate to Partner Support, and provide back any updates.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce may come back later.

But solved the deployment issue by adjusting our test method.
removing the RecordType Query, replacing it with Schema class capability.

Commented code was removed:

```
//list<recordType> RTs = [SELECT id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Asset' AND Name = 'Machine Asset'];
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult cfrSchema = Schema.SObjectType.Asset; 
Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> AssetRecordTypeInfo = cfrSchema.getRecordTypeInfosByName(); 
Id rtId = AssetRecordTypeInfo.get('Machine Asset').getRecordTypeId();

Asset a = new Asset();
//a.recordtypeId = RTs[0].id;
a.recordtypeId = rtId;
```